# Create datasource programatically to connect postgresdb

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to create datasource programatically to connect postgresDB. I am using below code to create datasource.

```
@Factory
public class HikariDataSourceFactory {

    @Singleton
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("--------------- Inside datasource --------------------");

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db");
        config.setUsername("username");
        config.setPassword("password");
        config.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");     
        config.setAllowPoolSuspension(true);
        
        return new HikariUrlDataSource(config);
    }
}
```

When I running the code, getting below error.

```
Message: Missing bean argument value: jdbcConfiguration
```

Updated Stacktrace

```
[INFO] Running com.example.FunctionRequestHandlerTest
15:16:38.804 [main] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment - Established active environments: [function, lambda]
15:16:38.810 [main] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$BootstrapEnvironment - Established active environments: [function, lambda]
15:16:38.834 [main] INFO  i.m.context.DefaultBeanContext - Reading bootstrap environment configuration
--------------- Inside datasource --------------------
15:16:39.405 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
15:16:39.836 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@19a64eae
15:16:39.838 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
15:16:41.904 [main] ERROR i.m.f.aws.MicronautRequestHandler - Exception initializing handler
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations]

Message: Missing bean argument value: jdbcConfiguration
Path Taken: new DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations(String dataSourceName,DataJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration,DataSource dataSource,ConnectionOperations connectionOperations,TransactionOperations transactionOperations,ExecutorService executorService,BeanContext beanContext,DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider,RuntimeEntityRegistry entityRegistry,DataConversionService conversionService,AttributeConverterRegistry attributeConverterRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver schemaTenantResolver,JdbcSchemaHandler schemaHandler,JsonMapper jsonMapper,SqlJsonColumnMapperProvider sqlJsonColumnMapperProvider) --> new DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations(String dataSourceName,[DataJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration],DataSource dataSource,ConnectionOperations connectionOperations,TransactionOperations transactionOperations,ExecutorService executorService,BeanContext beanContext,DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider,RuntimeEntityRegistry entityRegistry,DataConversionService conversionService,AttributeConverterRegistry attributeConverterRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver schemaTenantResolver,JdbcSchemaHandler schemaHandler,JsonMapper jsonMapper,SqlJsonColumnMapperProvider sqlJsonColumnMapperProvider)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1979)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3340)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3694)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:345)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:191)
    at io.micronaut.function.executor.AbstractExecutor.startEnvironment(AbstractExecutor.java:124)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.buildApplicationContext(MicronautRequestHandler.java:140)
    at io.micronaut.function.aws.MicronautRequestHandler.<init>(MicronautRequestHandler.java:67)
    at com.example.ExampleRequestHandler.<init>(ExampleRequestHandler.java:23)
    at com.example.FunctionRequestHandlerTest.setupServer(FunctionRequestHandlerTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:411)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:409)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.micronaut.data.jdbc.operations.DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations]
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Denis Please check updated stacktrace

Comment: You might need to create a fake config: datasources.default.fake = "ABC"

Comment: @Denis, i have added fake config. But getting error - Message: Error configuring data source 'default'. No URL specified

Comment: @Denis Getting this error - Multiple possible bean candidates found: [DataSource, DataSource]

Comment: You should exclude Micronaut Hikari or any other pool